# Get integers and floats from xml

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml2

I'm using tinyxml2 and I know how to get strings of attributes, but I want to also get integers, floats and booleans too. So, I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <tinyxml2.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace tinyxml2;

int main()
{
    XMLDocument doc;
    doc.LoadFile("sample.xml");

    XMLElement *titleElement = doc.FirstChildElement("specimen");

    int f = -1;
    if (!titleElement->QueryIntAttribute("age", &f))
        cerr << "Unable to get value!" << endl;

    cout << f << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And sample.xml being:

```
<?xml version=1.0?>

<specimen>
    <animal>
        Dog
    </animal>
    <age>
        12
    </age>
</specimen>
```

Don't worry, the xml file is just a fake sample, nothing real!

Anyway, I am still not able to get the integer value that's within the attribute 'age'. If this doesn't work, then how should I use tinyxml2 to get ints and floats from an xml document?

Comment: What error code is returned?

Comment: Well, age isn't an attribute, is it?  I believe an attribute would be within the <> and have `attribute="whatnot"`.

Comment: From what I can see, the QueryIntAttribute doesn't return the falsely value - shouldn't you rather be checking for the XML_NO_ERROR flag? It might be helpful if you have checked the returned value and added to your question - it may tell us what is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, that the correct method to use is `QueryIntText` not `QueryIntAttribute` - you are trying to get the value of an XML node, not attribute.

Consult the documentation for further details and usage:http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2docs/classtinyxml2_1_1_x_m_l_element.html#a8b92c729346aa8ea9acd59ed3e9f2378

Answer (score 1):

In your if statement you should test for failure like this:

```
if (titleElement->QueryIntAttribute("age", &f) != TIXML_SUCCESS )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to resolve my issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <tinyxml2.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace tinyxml2;

int main()
{
    XMLDocument doc;
    doc.LoadFile("sample.xml");

    auto age = doc.FirstChildElement("specimen")
                 ->FirstChildElement("age");

    int x = 0;

    age->QueryIntText(&x);

    cout << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Suffice it to say I got my xml terminology wrong so I confused attributes with text. At any rate, that's how I got the integer value from the xml doc.